# Copying 8 bit integer pattern into 32 bit integer efficiently?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Given an 8-bit integer 'c8', the bit pattern must be copied into a 32-bit integer, 'c32', such that 'c32' consists of 'c8' repeated 4 times. For example,

```
if c8 =     1000 1110, 
then c32 =  1000 1110 1000 1110 1000 1110 1000 1110
```

I've thought about this and came up with two methods in C. I'm not that experienced, however, and I'm unsure which method, if any, I should use in the final code.

Minimal Examples:

```
uint8_t c8 = 0b10001110;  // for this example

// method 1
uint32_t c32 = ((c8 << 8 | c8) << 16) | (c8 << 8 | c8); 

// method 2
uint16_t c16 = c8 << 8 | c8; 
uint32_t _c32 = c16 << 16 | c16;
```

Both methods work as expected, but I'm wondering which one would be considered 'better' from an experts' perspective :-). 

In the first method, I'm computing multiple shifts while in the second one I'm creating an extra variable. I'm not that experienced with low-level things (and the performance of such low-level things), and if anybody could point me in the right direction, or find a better way of doing this, I would appreciate that.

Thank you.

Comment: If "best" is defined as "fastest" then some profiling is in order.

Comment: does the performance matter for such a contrieved use case? how often do you need to do that in what time. optimize  when/where  needed is quite a nice aproach.

Comment: For larger areas of memory, the typical approach would be [`memset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset). For only four bytes you have to benchmark. And think about if any possible (and probably premature) optimization is really needed. Concentrate on writing good, readable, maintainable and working code first and foremost. Only optimize if it's needed, and then only the actual measured bottlenecks.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'll focus more on writing good, readable code and less on optimization. One more thing: in this case, which method would you personally consider easier to read @Someprogrammerdude? I think declaring an additional variable (method2) makes it easier to understand.

Comment: @travisjayday, none of the listed ones is readable. Use `memset`, everybody knows what this does, so everybody understands it immediately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best is to use `memset`. A *good* compiler considers it as an [intrinsic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_function) and optimizes it in the best way possible. I tested the following program with GCC 6.3.0, `-O3`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    uint32_t target;
    uint8_t byte;

    // if we don't do this, GCC could just *fold the value as a constant*
    scanf("%c", &byte);
    memset(&target, byte, sizeof(target));
    printf("%08" PRIX32 "\n", target);
}
```

What the generated machine code actually ended up doing *on my platform* was analogous to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    uint32_t target;
    uint8_t byte;
    scanf("%c", &byte); 

    target = 0x01010101UL * byte;
    printf("%08" PRIX32 "\n", target);
}
```

Comment: That's a good solution and much easier to read than all the shifting and or'ing. And thanks for linking the 'intrinsic' definition; it makes sense that that would perform the best.

Comment: @travisjayday in general, this applies to all of the C standard library functions may seem like they're function calls, but the C standard allows the compiler to always generate code that behaves *as if* they were called... Even the simplest one: `printf("Hello world\n");` => GCC would actually compile it to `puts("Hello world");`